# google maps and amazon appstore

Tags: android, maps, amazon-appstore

I created an android app that displays some coordinates on google maps after I got my map key from google developer console and the app worked just fine. So, I uploaded the app to amazon appstore to make it available for others to use it. Therefore, when some downloaded it to their mobile from mazon appsore they reported that the map shows empty screen I tried it from the store and it really showed no map on the screen but when I install it from my workspace it works very well!!!

any ideas!?

Comment: Are they on Kindle Fires?  If so, they won't have Google Maps because Amazon didn't pay for it.  They have their replacement for it, but its a separate API you'll need to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon devices do not support the Google Maps API, so you should use Amazon Maps Redirection by checking checkbox at Binary File(s) page (http://prntscr.com/6ml76e)

Comment: the users who downloaded it installed it on Samsung android mobiles such as galaxy s3 , s$ and note 3!!!

Comment: and by the way I have checked that checkbox! but the problem is still there!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon removes the signature you used to sign your app and re-signs it with an Amazon signature that is unique to you, does not change, and is the same for all apps in your account. This means that the SHA1 signature you registered in the Google Developer Console is no longer valid.

Ask Amazon to give you your new:
MD5
SHA1
SHA256
Public key exponent
Public key modulus
Facebook hash 
by using their contact function.

Then, use this SHA1 to add another line in the format SHA1;package_name in Google Maps authorisation segment in the Google Developers console.

Source: https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/submitting-your-app/tech-docs/submitting-your-app